# Unable to start an application using pywin32 package - invalid class string error

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I have installed Python 3.10 and installed the `pywin32` package.
I tried to open an application using Python, however I am facing an error: "invalid class string".

**Code:**

```
import win32com.client as win32
ecutest = win32.Dispatch('ECU-TEST 7.2.Application')
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Halos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 86, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Halos\Desktop\ECU_Test_Run.py", line 2, in <module>
    ecutest = win32.Dispatch('ECU-TEST 7.2.Application')
  File "C:\Users\Halos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 117, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch, userName, clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\Halos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 106, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Users\Halos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 88, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

Comment: The error means that no COM class is registered with that name. You have either typed in the name incorrectly, or the COM class is not registered on your system.

Comment: @DS_London: 
1. I manually opened the application and checked the name of the application from task manager and used the same in my code. Still facing the error
2. Checked and found that COM class is registered in my system

Comment: In general the name of the application in task manager will not be what you want. You want the name of the object as listed under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in the Registry. This is the 'ProgId` ... a (non-unique) string which can be used to look up the (somewhat opaque) CLSID for an object. The string you have does not conform to the requirements for a ProgId, in that is has a space in it. "The format of a ProgID is <Program>.<Component>.<Version>, separated by periods and with no spaces, as in Word.Document.6."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/-progid--key